# WCF client response is returning null from tcp ip server via sockets

Tags: wcf, sockets

I have created a tcp ip client and server as console application. And they are working fine using the netdatacontract serializer. Now I converted client console app as client library and want to consume this response from WCF service. I created this WCF service using nettcp binding. The problem I am facing is my response is always returned as null from client library, but the same client is working in console app without using this client in WCF service. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: couyld you share some code?

Comment: the code is vast.U want to me share client or server or wcf service code .Please clarify